# Parent with position relative and height auto not expanding to height of float children?

Tags: html, css, css-float, height

I have the following structure and as you will see in this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48ncjqvj/12/), the height of the `.parent` elements is not auto-expanding to the total height of their content.

What am I doing wrong ??

CSS

```
.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.parent{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top-width: 50px;
    border-bottom-width: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.float{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  background-color: blue;
}
.float:nth-child(2){
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="float"></div>
   <div class="float"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="float"></div>
   <div class="float"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="float"></div>
   <div class="float"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to your class parent, this will start a new "block formatting context". Then the parent will span the complete height of all children elements.

http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Comment: This makes no sense but it's working, so thanks! :-)

Answer (score -1):

use

> > min-height 
> >     instead of 
> >     height 
> >     in . float class